# actionFinally not running cmd invoked inside handler

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

I have the following code fragment:

```
withContainer :: String -> (String -> Action a) -> Action a
  cid <= cmd "docker" [ "run" , "--rm", "-d", my_image ]
  ... 
  actionFinally (action containerName) $ do
    cmd_ "docker" [ "rm", "-f", filter (/= '\n') cid ]
```

which supposedly kill containers whether or not the action succeeds. However I noticed containers are still left up and running when the action fails, which is annoying. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample of code looks correct, and testing variations of it in isolation does indeed work. A bug has been raised to figure out the precise reason it doesn't work in your case at https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/issues/731.